# Run function in page load with and without update panel

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

Please consider this scenario:

I have some pages that have 1 master page.some of them have update panel and some have not. I have a jQuery code that I want execute when user raise `keydown` event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myClass').on('keydown', function (e) {
         var MainCharKey = e.which.toString();
         ...
     })
})
```

I want to add this code to my master page and every `textbox` that has `myClass` css class uses this code.Problem is when I place this in my master page, in pages have update panel this code works just once(first time page load) and when any postback occurs this code does not work. If I change that code in this way:

```
function pageLoad(){
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.myClass').on('keydown', function (e) {
          var MainCharKey = e.which.toString();
           ...
        })
   })
}
```

this code does not work on pages without update panel.

How (Or Where) I can write this code that run with and without update panel?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to add event delegation

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.myClass', function (e) {
     var MainCharKey = e.which.toString();
     ...
});
```